# How to edit web.config to stop serving a specific file type of a .NET web app

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, web-config

I'd like to prevent users from accessing files of a certain type through their browser.  For example, the IIS server blocks access to .config and .vb files by default, giving the error message "The type of page you have requested is not served because it has been explicitly forbidden", and I'd like to add other file types to this behavior.

Is there something I can add to the application's web.config file?  I'd rather not handle it by blocking directory access using the `<authorization>` element.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In IIS 7+, request filtering can be done at the app level.  Add the below code in  web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <fileExtensions>
                <add fileExtension=".vbs" allowed="false" />
            </fileExtensions>
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

For IIS 6, the above won't work but you can mimic the default blocking behavior that exists for pages like .cs files, although you may have to make changes on the server side.  First, add the below into your app's web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
        <add path="*.vbs" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" validate="True"/>
    </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

If asp.net is set up to handle that file type, like .cs, then you're done.  However, if the file type you mean to block is handled by IIS, not asp.net (like .vbs), this won't be enough.  You'll have to make changes in IIS Manager to map the file extension as shown [here](http://blog.tylerholmes.com/2008/10/stop-aspnet-from-serving-specific-file.html).

Comment: This is great, thanks. How woud you specify which directory, though? I can't work out how to add the file path to the folder I want to secure.

Comment: Note the docs state that the Request Filtering role service may have to be installed on the server first, as stated here http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/hiddensegments. It is installed by default.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `location` node in Web.Config

```
<location path=".">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <!-- Order and case are important below -->
                <allow roles="Admin"/>
                <deny users="*"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
```

Using path `"."` will apply to the current folder and all nested folders. More specific paths can be provided. You can also have nested web.configs inside your folder hierarchy to easily make one folder more or less permissive.

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/b6x6shw7.aspx

Comment: Thanks - I know this works, but I'm looking to block the file type, not the directory or file name.

Comment: It can be really useful to have additional web.configs on the server that might not be in the project ensuring that code deployments are unable to alter server security configurations.

Answer (score 2):

**Why store non-web-served files in a folder available through IIS at all**?  I usually do something like:

```
\www.mywebsite.com\wwwroot\
\www.mywebsite.com\secureimages\
\www.mywebsite.com\virutaldirectories\
```

In IIS my wwwroot is the root of my website, and my MVC application is service images from the secureimages directory via [This.File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492492%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) so the images aren't available unless I've allowed it via programmatically.  I'd assume your program is also serving files, and if so, those files don't need to be available in any way to IIS to serve directly as files.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to block file types through web.config, so I think this is the best answer since it's at the app level - thanks.

Comment: I found a couple of ways to do it through web.config so I've updated the accepted answer.

Comment: In some cases this just isn't possible. Like hackers using a php exploit to put files where they don't belong. (grrrrr) Restricting filetypes like this is good redundancy.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using IIS 7 this can be done on the 
ApplicationHost.config level.

http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/introduction-to-applicationhostconfig

Request Filtering section:
http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering

Files will appear as 404 return code.

*Note: Because this config is at the root level, changes apply to all applications running on that server.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for something at the app level.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to setup IIS to run those file requests through the .NET pipeline.  A better strategy would be to just block the items from IIS to begin with.  That way, you don't have the overhead of running, say, PDFs through the .NET pipeline just to block the file.

Answer (score 0):

Request Filtering should do it.  It does not have an explicit extension.  You could use Regex on the URL.

[IIS 7.0 Request Filtering and URL Rewriting](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/iis-request-filtering-and-url-rewriting)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for something at the app level.