# Server.Transfer + Jquery '$' is undefined

Tags: c#, asp.net

my json method works fine when i use this:

```
Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
```

But when i use

```
Server.Transfer(string.Format("~/Default.aspx");
```

it give me error that '$ is undefined'

assume currently i am in routing.aspx page.

Comment: _Can any body know the syntax?_ What? Did you tried to use Google first?

Comment: You would need to add something in your Web.Config to block routes.

Comment: @SonerGönül: Yes i tried a bit on google, but my internet speed is very slow write now (don't laugh :p) so can't i surf much

Comment: @Killrawr: are you sure ? i am doing a little testing then came back to you.

Comment: Yeah look at something along these [lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12412915/how-to-edit-web-config-to-stop-serving-a-specific-file-type-of-a-net-web-app), also look into some videos on [Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/).

Comment: actually my problem was json method not working properly, i thought it was due to url re-writing, after some testing i found i am wrong, i am going to edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i give the complete path to the jquery in head tag of the page.

change:

```
 <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="http://localhost:50847/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

i know hard code is not the good practice but i will optimize it, for now may this can help people like me.